# Mysql HEX function to decode multi-byte utf8

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, character-encoding, mysqli

MySQL uses a function HEX() which will convert a sequence of characters to hexidecimal representation. The only problem is that it assumes each character is two-bytes. This is fine for most cases, but with utf-8 there are sometimes characters that span more than 2-bytes.

For example. 0xEFBFBD is the three byte character used to signal an encoding error. When I have two of these character one after the other in the DB (6 bytes in total), in a utf8 encoded table, and I try SELECT HEX(col1) FROM table ..., this comes out as 0xC3AFC2BFC2BD rather than 0xEFBFBD. If I select it using a query in php, and then convert is to hex within php, it comes through as the correct format.

What would be the best is a function is MySql which can decode proper, multi-byte UTF8. I'm very surprised that it appears not to exists and would like to know if anyone else has found this to be the case also and possible work-arounds.

The closest thing I've found to an answer in MySql is:
http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?103,375304,375660

but this advice doesn't really help. I'll post a test case later if no one has any ideas off the top of their head.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `HEX` function returns the bytes that are actually stored; remember that MySQL happily stores a mixture of character encodings. If you obtain two bytes for every character, your values must be encoded in [`ucs2` or `utf16`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-unicode-sets.html). To check the encoding you can use the [`CHARSET` function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-functions.html#function_charset).

It looks like in this particular case the column contains 쎯슿슽 (U+C3AF U+C2BF U+C2BD) encoded in UTF-16. There must be some other issue that makes you believe �� (U+FFFD U+FFFD) is the stored value. Perhaps your PHP program is using `ucs2` or `utf16` as the connection character set and then treats the obtained text as if it was UTF-8?

---

**Update**: To get the hexadecimal representation of the UTF-8 encoding of a string -- any string, in any encoding*) --, use `HEX(CONVERT(string USING utf8))`. For example:

```
set @unknown = char(0xFFFD using ucs2);        -- stored bytes: \xFF \xFD
select hex(convert(@unknown using utf8));      -- output: EFBFBD
```

*) Except binary strings that don't have an encoding to convert from

Comment: Actually, both the table charset and php are utf-8. The �� characters are in the original file that I've been given to process. IE I've had a look in hexedit at the raw data for this file and it has two 0xEFBFBD's one after the other. So this is getting correctly stored in the DB as 0xEFBFBD. However if I want to write a script in sql to fix these characters it seems difficult without a multibyte HEX decoding function in SQL. I've overcome the problem using PHP, but I am still interested if anyone knows of a tweak to MySql HEX function that allows correct decoding of utf-8.

Comment: Note that if I select it using a query in php, and then convert it to hex within php, it is correctly represented as 0xEFBFBD.

Comment: Then it looks like the problem is with the way you insert data: the column does not contain two U+FFFD characters. As to how to get the hex representation of the UTF-8 encoding of a string, see update.

Comment: This SELECT `col`, HEX(CONVERT(`col` using utf8)) FROM `table` is working great now. I did actually find that some of the variables from the "SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%char%'" were still set to latin_1 and this could have been part of the problem. On a related note, I've found that some other characters require the mysqli_set_charset($conn, "utf8"); to be encoded correctly in the DB.